# Simple BMI calculation with two additional fields

Tags: javascript, html

So I have the following form which calculates the users BMI and redirects the user to a certain page depending on the result:

**HTML**

```
<form name="bmiForm">
   <p>Your Weight(kg): <input type="text" name="weight"></p>
   <p>Your Height(cm): <input type="text" name="height"></p>

   <input type="button" value="Calculate BMI" onClick="calculateBmi()"><br />

   <p>Your BMI: <input type="text" name="bmi" size="10"></p>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
    function calculateBmi() {

    var weight = document.bmiForm.weight.value
    var height = document.bmiForm.height.value

    if(weight > 0 && height > 0) {
       var finalBmi = weight/(height/100*height/100)
       document.bmiForm.bmi.value = finalBmi

       if(finalBmi < 30){
          window.location.href = 'http://localhost:8888/?page_id=146';
       }

       if(finalBmi > 30){
          window.location.href = 'http://localhost:8888/?page_id=149';
       }
     }
    }
</script>
```

It works an absolute treat. However, I now need two more inputs.

1. Have you tried diet and exercise?
2. Have you ever had diabetes?

So I would obviously need a select option for "Yes" and "No" for each and added functionality within the if statement.

I tried adding:

```
var diabetes = document.bmiForm.diabetes.value
```

To the script and then another condition within the if statement, but no luck.

Where can I go from here? Any suggestions for accomplishing the above.

**Any** help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For checkbox you have to do like this :

```
 if (document.getElementById('diabetes').checked) {    //here 'diabetes' is id of checkbox
        alert("checked");
    }
 else { alert("not checked") }
```

and for dropdown do as :

```
var e = document.getElementById("diabetes");
var selectvalue= e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;  //you can get selected value with this
var selecttext= e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;    //you can get selected text with this
```

Comment: Thanks Exception. Much appreciated. That makes sense. So if I can select the value/text of the drop-down they select, I could change the if statement to reflect that? e.g. if(finalBmi > 35 && selecttext="Yes") { } .. something along those lines?

Comment: @Pete...yes.. you can put the condition inside if as you require here i have given a simple demo that how to use checkbox or dropdown ..